Transforming Data in Spotfire (Combining Columns)
I am trying to create single columns from multiple columns in Spotfire and can't quite get it right. Currently my data is in this format (I have a column for each item I would prefer to have as a row based on the subject):
Current table format
I would like to transform it to this:
table format I would like
Any help greatly appreciated!
I have only tried pivoting but this has not worked.

You can do it with a few transformations on the data canvas, but if you have a variable number of students, that would not be repeatable.
Can you elaborate?

I only have 6 "students" with respective grades and days in class, so want to repeat the subjects up to 6 time (6 rows for each subject for each student).

Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Create a copy of the existing table, by clicking on + then choosing Other and selecting the current table
Call new table e.g. data_1
Apply transformation: Unpivot
Columns to pass through: Subject
Columns to transform: Student 1 Grade, Student 2 Grade etc.
Category column name: Student
Value column name: Grade
Apply transformation: Calculate and replace column
on column: Student
expression: RXExtract([Student],'\d',1)
Repeat for Student days in class, creating a second table data_2
Join the two tables (i.e. Add columns to data_1 from data_2) by Subject and Student.
You will end up with table data_1 containing the data in the format you asked for.
